# Waiting for network call to finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a network request and wait for it to finish, so that I can make a decission what should be apps next step.
Normally I would avoid such solution, but this is a rare case in which codebase has a lot of legacy and we don't have enough time to apply necessary changes in order to *make things right*.

I'm trying to write a simple input-output method with following definition:

```c
- (nullable id<UserPaymentCard>)validCardForLocationWithId:(ObjectId)locationId;
```

The thing is that in order to perform some validation inside this method I need to make a network request just to receive neccessary information, so I'd like to wait for this request to finish.

First thing that popped in my mind was using `dispatch_semaphore_t`, so I ended up with something like this:

```c
- (nullable id<UserPaymentCard>)validCardForLocationWithId:(ObjectId)locationId {
    id<LocationsReader> locationsReader = [self locationsReader];

    __block LocationStatus *status = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [locationsReader fetchLocationProviderStatusFor:locationId completion:^(LocationStatus * _Nonnull locationStatus) {
        status = locationStatus;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    } failure:nil];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return [self.paymentCards firstCardForStatus:status];
}
```

Everything compiles and runs, but my UI freezes and I actually never receive sempahore's signal.
So, I started playing with `dispatch_group_t` with exactly the same results.

Look like I might have some problems with where code gets executed, but I don't know how to approach this and get the expected results. When I try wrapping everything in `dispatch_async` I actually stop blocking main queue, but `dispatch_async` return immediatelly, so I `return` from this method before the network request finishes.

What am I missing? Can this actually be acheived without some `while` hacks? Or am I trying to fight windmills?

---

I was able to achieve what I want with the following solution, but it really feels like a hacky way and not something I'd love to ship in my codebase.

```
- (nullable id<UserPaymentCard>)validCardForLocationWithId:(ObjectId)locationId {
    id<LocationsReader> locationsReader = [self locationsReader];

    __block LocationStatus *status = nil;
    __block BOOL flag = NO;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [locationsReader fetchLocationProviderStatusFor:locationId completion:^(LocationStatus * _Nonnull locationStatus) {
            status = locationStatus;
            flag = YES;
        } failure:nil];
    });

    while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true) && !flag){};

    return [self.paymentCards firstCardForStatus:status];
}
```

Comment: I would recomed to do async code and show a Hud to wait for the async task conclution, since is not recomendable to lock UI waiting for task like this.

Comment: @kjoe as I've mentioned I'm not happy with this approach either. The thing is I cannot do this differently at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `fetchLocationProviderStatusFor:completion:failure:` calls those callbacks in main queue. That's why you get deadlock. It's impossible. We can't time travel yet.

Answer (score 1):

The deprecated `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest` API is useful for those instances when you really can't (or just can't be bothered to) do things properly, like this example:

```swift
    private func pageExists(at url: URL) -> Bool {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.timeoutInterval = 10
        var response: URLResponse?
        try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request,
                                                    returning: &response)
        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 { return false }
        if httpResponse.url != url { return false }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your method causes work to be done on the main thread, which freezes the UI. Your solution works, but it would be best to change the method to include a completion block. Then, you could call the completion block at the end of the async block. Here's the example code for that:

```
- (void)validCardForLocationWithId:(ObjectId)locationId completion:(nullable id<UserPaymentCard> (^)(void))completion {
    id<LocationsReader> locationsReader = [self locationsReader];
    __block LocationStatus *status = nil;
    [locationsReader fetchLocationProviderStatusFor:locationId completion:^(LocationStatus * _Nonnull locationStatus) {
        status = locationStatus;
        completion([self.paymentCards firstCardForStatus:status]);
    } failure:nil];
}
```